# Delphi - TForm and Generics

Tags: forms, delphi, generics, vcl, tform

I'm wondering if its possible, in Delphi, to be able to define a base form class deriving from TForm with a generic. The application I'm working on interacts with various hardware devices (via serial port, usb, ethernet, etc) and I'm wanting each device to be able to display a property form containing properties specific to that device.

So far I have the following code...

```
// DEVICE MODEL...

// Interface defining a device
IDevice = interface 
    procedure ShowPropertyForm;
    // ... Other procedures and functions
end;

// Abstract base device class
TDevice = class(IDevice)
    protected
        // Override this function to show their property form
        procedure DoShowPropertyForm; virtual; abstract;

    public
        // Calls Self.DoShowPropertyForm;
        procedure ShowPropertyForm;
end;

TSerialDevice = class(TDevice)
    protected
        // Creates and shows the TSerialDeviceForm below
        procedure DoShowPropertyForm; override;
end;

// Represents a device capable of providing positioning information
TGpsDevice = class(TSerialDevice)
    protected
        // Creates and shows the TGpsDeviceForm below
        procedure DoShowPropertyForm; override;
end;

// FORM MODEL...

// Represents a base form, with skinning functionality, etc
TBaseForm = class(TForm)

end;

// Base device properties form, allows the form to access a strongly-typed
// version of the IDevice
TDeviceForm<T : IDevice> = class(TBaseForm)

    private
        FDevice : T;

    public
        // Accessor for the associated IDevice
        property Device : T read FDevice write FDevice;
end;

// Property form for a TSerialDevice, has controls for controlling port name
// baud rate, stop/start bits, etc
TSerialDeviceForm = class(TDeviceForm<TSerialDevice>)

end;

// Property form for a TGpsDevice, has controls in addition to what is
// provided by the TSerialDeviceForm
TGpsDeviceForm = class(TSerialDeviceForm) 

end;
```

The issue comes when trying to access the form designer. As an example, the TBaseForm contains an "OK" and a "Cancel" button. I want to add additional functionality to the TDeviceForm however when I attempt to open the designer, the following error appears...

> Error creating form: Root class not found: "".

Likewise, if I attempt to open the TGpsDeviceForm designer, I get the following error...

> Error creating form: Ancestor for 'TSerialDeviceForm' not found.

I'm assuming that the Delphi form designer cannot handle generics but could there be a better way around this issue?

In the DFM files, for everything other than the TBaseForm, I've altered the first line from:

> object DeviceForm: TDeviceForm
>   to
>   inherited DeviceForm: TDeviceForm

However this seems to make no difference.

Please can anyone offer any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So far as I know, visual form inheritance cannot be used with generic types.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had a feeling that this may have been the case, although I did get to a point yesterday where I was able to access the form designers of things like the TSerialDeviceForm and TGpsDeviceForm however this morning, it isn't playing ball - must have been pure luck!

Comment: If you introduce generic parameter lower down the hierarchy, after you have finished with VFI, then you are fine.

Comment: I'm not sure where else I could introduce the generic parameter and still achieve what I want - ultimately, the TDeviceForm still needs the generic to allow correct type-access to descendant forms. I may need a complete re-think.

Comment: Small world, you appear to live 5 miles from where I work!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem, but why generics? Form inheritance seems exactly right for this kind of problem.

Comment: My thinking was that introducing the generic - at the TDeviceForm level - was a simple way of providing access to the correct TDevice type through the Device property defined in TDeviceForm in the right descendant form.

Comment: I can remove the generic and introduce a field in each of the descendant forms but this seems a little wasteful - and I need a type-cast in each of the forms constructors.

Comment: As I understand it, the forms are different for different devices, but share some basic controls. That is an ideal situation for the classic inheritance, and not for generics at all.

Comment: This is correct, for example the TSerialDeviceForm has controls for port name, baud rate, etc - the TGpsDeviceForm which inherits from this has these controls plus other controls for controlling NMEA sentences. The generic is purely in place to ensure that when accessing the Device property of the form, I'm accessing the correct type at that point - rather than having to cast it first.

Comment: @weblar83 Where would that be? There aren't many places 5 miles from me!!

Comment: If you're in Ulverston, I'm in Haverthwaite!

Comment: Small world indeed. Out of interest, if you don't mind my asking, who employs you around here that develops using Delphi?

Comment: No, I don't mind you asking - I work for a company called Blueprint Subsea (www.blueprintsubsea.com)

Comment: Looks interesting. Another of the multitude of subsea related businesses in the South Lakes. I'm with http://www.orcina.com.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment Delphi does not support the presence of generics in DFM files. However, considering what you explained in some comments, I understood that you have a problem is similar to one I had in the past.

In my case, what I did was a mix of visual form inheritance and the use of frames. Being more specific, I had to create a hierarchy of forms and a hierarchy of frames and use them together in order to have a specific form that should be able to work with a specific object. The forms didn't much when working on a given particular object, the frames were responsible for this kind of specific handling.

The frames had properies with the correct object types, so I got a certain level of type checking from the compiler, specially in the most complex code, but in some portions I had to check the types myself, precisely because I could not use generics.

Maybe this model will fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I understand correctly, it was your frames that had the functionality to work with specific objects? I've come up with a solution that seems to work, minus the generics so no type-checking. Not entirely sure how to post it here as its not "the answer" but good enough for what I need.

Comment: Correct, the Frames are dedicated to work on specific objects. Inside the frames code the type checking is garanteed by the compiler. Outside, in the forms code, type checking had to be in runtime and eventually I had to generate exceptions.